# JMETER - response assertion -> Response was null

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, assertion

I have checked several options how to validate response and it still not works in my case.
As you can see (Debug sampler), for last_name regex works and I receive some values, but if I want to reuse this response as "Response assertion", test failed, because I receive "Response was null".

[JSON Extractor for last_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biFFR.png)

[Response assertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MUGs.png)

[Test failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmGEk.png)

Also, I would like to count objects in "data", so I used [http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/?path=$..book[0,1]](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/?path=$..book%5B0,1%5D) to make sure, the JSON file is correct. But "Debug sampler" shows me nothing :( so test failed again

[Count of objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsYdt.png)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYGrl.png)

Any idea how to solve this problem please ?

JSON:

```
{
"page": 2,
"per_page": 6,
"total": 12,
"total_pages": 2,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 7,
        "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Michael",
        "last_name": "Lawson",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Lindsay",
        "last_name": "Ferguson",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "email": "tobias.funke@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Tobias",
        "last_name": "Funke",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/9-image.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "email": "byron.fields@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Byron",
        "last_name": "Fields",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/10-image.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "email": "george.edwards@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "George",
        "last_name": "Edwards",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/11-image.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "email": "rachel.howell@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Rachel",
        "last_name": "Howell",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/12-image.jpg"
    }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to tick `Compute concatenation var` in JSON Extractor, otherwise you will get 2 separate [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

   ```
   lastName_1=Lawson
   lastName_2=Ferguson
   ```

   [image]
2. In addition to point 1 you need to use `lastName_ALL` in the [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)
3. You need to switch from `Matches` to `Substring` in "Pattern Matching Rules" of the Response assertion

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)

Comment: Thank you ! It works :) And about counting.... it does not return any value at all. Any idea, please ?